# Is it possible to know how many times a user connected to an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to know how many times a user connected to an Oracle database?

If possible where we can find this information?

Answer (score 2):

If audit is enabled, you can check DBA_AUDIT_SESSION/USER_AUDIT_SESSION (More info about auditing - [Audit doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/audit.htm#1975)). Another option is to check dba_hist_active_sess_history - you will need to write a query that counts distinct serials/sessions to get rough number of user logins assuming user did anything during the session. Also, you won't be able to go too far in the past with dba_hist_active_sess_history - it's a view based on tables populated by AWR which automatically deletes old records (as far as I remember default retention period is 1 week ).

Answer (score 0):

You could use after logon to database trigger for this purpose also.

For example, create table with columns of your interest ( username, machine, program...), then create after logon trigger and populate your table with data from v$session. Or from some other system table, whatever best suits your needs.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm